# How to change the value of variable with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gcc, gdb

I have a file named exploit.c inside which:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char y1 = 'a';
const char y2 = 'b';
const char y3 = 'x';
const char y4 = 'y';
const char y5 = 'i';
const char y6 = 'j';

char x1 = 'f' ^ 'a';
char x2 = 'l' ^ 'b';
char x3 = 'a' ^ 'x';
char x4 = 'g' ^ 'y';
char x5 = 'y' ^ 'i';
char x6 = '-' ^ 'j';

int main() {
  bool c = false;
  if(c) { printf("The flag is: %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", x1 ^ y1, x2 ^ y2, x3 ^ y3, x4 ^
  y4, x4 ^ y4, x5 ^ y5, x6 ^ y6, x1 ^ y1, x2 ^ y2, x3 ^ y3, x4 ^ y4); }
  return 0;
}
```

I know I can print out the flag by changing the value of c. But I want to do it by assembling/executing. How can I print out the flag without changing the value of boolean but with gcc and gdb?

Comment: Use a bunch of print commands such as `p/c x1 ^ y1` (that's assuming the compiler did not optimize those out). You can also override the program counter so execution goes to the `printf`.

Comment: @Jester Yes, I want to override the bool c but the problem is I don't know how to do it

Comment: Start with a tutorial "How to use GDB"... -- GDB has built-in help, use the command "help".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via `gdb`. The first thing you have to know is that `c` is a local variable, that means that it will be placed on the stack in an un-optimized build that doesn't optimize it away entirely and remove dead code.

At this point you have two options: you can either modify the memory location where the variable is (so somewhere on the stack) or you can use [gdb assignment](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Assignment.html#Assignment).

To set the memory you can use something like `set *((char *) address_of_c) = 1`. (`bool` and `char` have the same size on most architectures, and bool uses 0 or non-0 as false/true.)  You could probably just use `bool*`.

With gdb assignment the same memory zone will be modified, but that depends on GDB being able to use debug symbols (created by `gcc -g`) to find the name and location of a local variable within this function's stack frame.  That's nice if it's available: you don't have to find the address of your variable manually.

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty easy one so I could do myself:)
We have exploit.c file where I need to debug it in order to get the flag with 'gcc'. I run the program with:

`gcc -g exploit.c -o exploit` and got 'exploit' which is executable `exploit.c` file.

Then: `gdb exploit`

We have `bool c = false;` on line 21, so put the break line on it:

```
break 21
```

Then: I changed the value of c by this command: `set variable c = “true”`
However, when I went to the  next line by “next” it become false again.
So I reset the value again: `set variable c = “true”` and then next button:
Yay, it printed out the flag:

```
(gdb) next

The flag is: flaggy-flag
23    return 0;
```

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on a line, it asks the debugger to stop the program just *before* that line is executed.

Comment: Small fix: `set variable c = "true"` works only by coincidence; it puts the (possibly truncated) address of the string `"true"` into `c`, and your compiled program likely treats any nonzero value of `c` as true. It's better to do `set variable c = true`.

Comment: Didn't you say `without changing the value of boolean`? But here you change the boolean.